# jQuery/CSS: Div inherit width of dynamically resizable image

Tags: html, dynamic, resize, width, inheritance

I have an image that is dynamically resizable.

The image is part of a gallery, so on the top/right corner, I have thumbnails to view images in that gallery.

Both the thumbs and image are contained within a div with class `.slider`.

The `.slider` div always stretches to width of browser, and the thumbs are positioned relative to the `.slider`.

If I can get the `.slider` div to always reflect the width of the image, it would be perfect, because then the thumbs would always flush right with the image (instead of the browser window, as it does now).

Remember the image is dynamically resizable vertically and horizontally, so I had to strip the image width and height.

Here is link of actual sample: http://peteryang.com/v02/image/tylenol/

Answer (score 0):

Attach an event on the image load or show or resize using jQuery (just google it) and in the event handler find the width and height of the image and set the width and height of your parent div

```
$("#imageid").resize(function(){
    //set the dimensions of the div
});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. Should something like this work? I tried and to no avail...
            
    `<script>
    $('.slides_control img').load(function() {
        $('.slider').width($('.slides_control img').width());
    }); 
    $('.slides_control img').resize(function(){
       $('.slider').width($('.slides_control img').width());
    });
    </script>`

Comment: Put all the contents of your script tag inside: 
$(document).ready(function(){
 //...put the contents here...
});
Also, do an alert inside your load function, just to make sure it's getting fired or not
$('.slides_control img').load(function() { 
 alert('test');
 $('.slider').width($('.slides_control img').width()); 
}); 
//don't do the alert in your resize function because that will get fired like crazy in IE